# How to catch an URL only if it ends by two specific characters using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to catch URLs that end only by /s examples:

www.example.com/contact/s
www.example.com/test/s

All of them have to be redirected (301) to:

www.example.com/s

But, if I have some page like www.example.com/system it should not be redirected, even it containing /s.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[^/]+/s$ /s
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/s$ /s [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I changed the first one to RedirectMatch 301 [^/]+/s$ /s and it worked. Thanks! :)